# Unable to Sum formula in VS Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, sum

So I'm trying to sum a formula in visual studio crystal reports but only for the group level.

I have a one to many relationship of Contract to Ancillary_Charge. I'm trying to sum Contract.Cost, but also show each ancillary_charge. So I've set CONTRACT.ID as a group, and each ancillary charge as the detail.

The following is my formula for the ChargePrice

```
if ({@IsZero} or {@ShowPrice} = false) then 0 else {CONTRACT.CONTRACT_COST}
```

The formula for IsZero

```
({PAYMENT_TYPE.ID} = 1) and IsNull({CHARGE_STATUS.PAYMENT_STATUS});
```

The formula for ShowPrice figures out if it is at the group level and returns true or false

```
Global booleanvar thingy;
Global booleanvar otherthingy;

if (isNull({@Previous}) and thingy = false) then
  thingy := true
else
  thingy := false;

if otherthingy then
  thingy := true;
otherthingy := false;

if (isNull({@Previous}) = false and next({CONTRACT.ID})<>{CONTRACT.ID}) then
  otherthingy := true;

thingy
```

When I try to Sum ChargePrice, it tells me that "This field cannot be summarized".

Why? and else can I do what I'm trying to do, namely only add to the sum when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting crystal to do the summation, do it yourself.

Create two extra formulas

**fmlReset**

```
Global NumberVar Total;
Total:=0;
```

**fmlDisplay**

```
Global NumberVar Total;
Total
```

Change your chargeprice formula to

```
Global NumberVar Total;
if ({@IsZero} or {@ShowPrice} = false) then 
0;
else 
Total:=Total+{CONTRACT.CONTRACT_COST};
```

Place fmlReset in your page report header or whenever you want to reset your total.  Place fmlDisplay where you want to display the total.